# Getting segmentation core dump error when running

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void encrypt(char inputText[20], int inputLength, int key);
void decrypt(int cipherText[20], int inputLength, int key);


FILE* fp;
char* mappingFile;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  char inputText[20],temp;
  int key,mode,inputLength, cipherText[20],i;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "-i")==0){
      mappingFile=argv[2];
  }else if (strcmp(argv[1],"-k")==0){
      key=atoi(argv[2]);
  }else if (strcmp(argv[1],"-m")==0){
      mode = atoi(argv[2]);
  }else{
       printf("invalid argument %s. Please re-run the program\n",argv[1]);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (strcmp(argv[3],"-i")==0){
     mappingFile = argv[4];
  }else if (strcmp(argv[3],"-k")==0){
     key=atoi(argv[4]);
  }else if (strcmp(argv[3],"-m")==0){
     mode = atoi(argv[4]);
  }else{printf("invalid argument %s. Please re-run the program\n",argv[3]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (strcmp(argv[5],"-i")==0){
      mappingFile=argv[6];
  }else if (strcmp(argv[5],"-k")==0){
      key=atoi(argv[6]);
  }else if (strcmp(argv[5],"-m")==0){
      mode=atoi(argv[6]);
  }else{
      printf("invalid argument %s. Please re-run the program\n",argv[5]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (key >25){
      printf("You entered %d. Sorry, your key must be between 1 and 25. Re-                    run the program and try again\n", key);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (mode !=1 &&mode!=2){
      printf("Unidentified mode. Run again!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fp=fopen(mappingFile,"r");
  if  (fp==NULL){
      printf("Cannot open mapping file\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (mode==1){
     printf("Enter the word you want to encrypt, upto 20 characters ");
     scanf("%20s", inputText);
     inputLength= strlen(inputText);

     encrypt(inputText, inputLength, key);
  }
  if (mode==2){
     printf("Enter the encrypted word you want to decrypt, upto 20 soace-     separated numbers. Put any letter at the end of your message ");
     i = 0;
     printf("Enter the encrypted word you want to decrypt, upto 20 soace-separated numbers. Put any letter at the end of your message ");
     i = 0;
     do{
         scanf("%d%c",&cipherText[i],&temp);
         i++;
      } while (temp ==' ');
      }
      inputLength=i;
      decrypt(cipherText, inputLength,key);
      }

void encrypt(char inputText[20], int inputLength, int key){
    int i,a,numb,character;
    char inputLetter,letter,String[20];
    for(a=0;a<=(inputLength-1);a = a+1){
       inputLetter = inputText[a];
       fopen(mappingFile,"r");
       while (fscanf(fp, "%c, %d", &letter, &numb)!=EOF){
           if (letter == inputLetter){
               String[a]=(numb-key+26);
               fclose(fp);
               break;
            }
       }
     }
     for (i=0;i<(inputLength);i++){
         character = String[i];
         printf("%d ",character);
     }
     printf("\n");
 }

void decrypt(int cipherText[20], int inputLength, int key){
     int i,a,numb,temp,inputNumber,character;
     char String[20],letter;

     for(a=0;a<=(inputLength-1);a = a+1){
         inputNumber = cipherText[a];
         i = 0;
         fopen(mappingFile,"r");
         temp=(inputNumber+key);
         if (temp>26){
            temp = temp -26;
         }
         while (fscanf(fp, "%c, %d", &letter, &numb)!=EOF){
            if (numb == temp){
                String[a] = letter;
                fclose(fp);
                break;
            }else{
               i++;
            }
         }
      }

      for (i=0;i<(inputLength);i++){
          character = String[i];
          printf("%c",character);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
```

A very very simple encryption/decryption program. From a .csv file it reads in a schema, which when paired with the input key provides the encryption decryption information. Works perfectly does everything i need it to, prints out expected output. But I get segmentation fault dumped afterwards and i have no idea why

Comment: I thought indentation was supposed to make code *easier* to read... some consistency in that would help.

Comment: char* mappingFile; here you have declared mappingfile as charecter pointer, and have used them as array if (strcmp(argv[1], "-i")==0){ mappingFile=argv[2]; without allocating memory for it, ie; no space is allotted by you to mappingFile and you are accessing it. Hence dump

Comment: sorry, tried to clean it up a bit

Comment: @SweekriteeSingh so after reading your comment i changed all instances of mappingFile to mappingFile[0] to reference the first position in the array which is the text file I need. However I am still receiving the same dump

Comment: Instead of that, you should allocate memory. Use: malloc

Comment: What @SweekriteeSingh mentioned about `mappingFile` is incorrect... it was ok as it was.  You do have something strange going on with when you open/close the file, though.  Actually, I'd be surprised if this program worked for more than a 1-char string.

Comment: @Dmitri the weird thing is it is inconsistent on when the Dump occurs. Sometimes it wont dump the first run through but then the second run through with the same string it will. Thus my confusion

Comment: You're opening the mapping file in `main()`, assigned to global `FILE* fp`.  But then in `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`, you open it again, discarding the return from `fopen()` and leaving `fp` unchanged, before looking up each character's mapping... and close `fp` when the mapping is found.  This means `fp` is only valid for the first lookup... you have the file open (multiple times), but no way to access those extra copies you've opened and the `FILE *` you're using isn't valid after the first `fclose()`.

Comment: Instead of opening and closing the file in `encrypt()`/`decrypt()`, just seek to the beginning (with eg. `fseek()`) before the lookups, and close `fp` at the end of the program.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. I have changed the structure so the file is opened once in main and then used the rewind function to return to the top when mapping is found. Still a dump. I am sorry if this seems trivial but i am lost

Comment: It also only seems to occur when running the encrypt portion...

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake... an out of place bracket. Thanks for your time!